# C# exceptions and code breaking

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, exception

I have a method called `TryMe` which has try catch block and catches his exceptions.
I call him from another class, but when an exception occurs it doesn't stop the code execution.
Example:

```
public void TryMe()
{
    try
    {
        SomeMethod();
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
}


     //Method calling
     Actions CAactions = new Actions();
     CActions.TryMe();
     ///////////////////////////////////
     //If exception is handled it should stop to here.

     this.Hide();
     FormActions FormActions = new FormActions();
```

The method definition is in class file. The method calling is in the windows form.
The problem is that it just shows the messagebox and the code execution continues.
I want to stop the code after the exception catching and not hiding the form. If everything is okay it should hide it.
Maybe my conceptions is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest fix would be to change your funcion to return true/false depending on whether it succeeded or not (i.e. only hide the form if the TryMe method didn't get an error):

```
 public bool TryMe()
 {
  try
   {
    SomeMethod();
    return true;
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
    // log exception 
    return false;
   }
  }
```

and call it like this:

```
 if (CActions.TryMe())
 {
   this.Hide();
 }
```

Another option would be to re throw the exception after showing the message, and have the calling code handle it in a try catch:

```
public void TryMe()
{
 try
 {
   SomeMethod();
  }
   catch (Exception exception)
  {
   // log exception? 
   throw;
  }
  }
```

calling code:

```
   try 
   {
     CActions.TryMe();
     this.Hide();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // error handling
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this a good coding practice? I'm newbie to C# and if my whole error handling model thinking is wrong, the best moment to change it is right now. :)

Comment: There are a number of options - you could rethrow the error from TryMe (by putting Throw() in the catch block) and have the calling code also handle the error

Comment: Sure, this is an option. But which one is the best? I mean the balance between accurate working, clean and readable code?

Comment: I think it boils down to if the exception is expected and you know your method can deal with it, then go down the bool route - if the exception is just that - an exception - then the calling code should have the try/catch

Answer (score 2):

Another option is delegate control flow to a caller, so :

```
public void TryMe()
{
    try
    {
        SomeMethod();
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
       throw;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
 Actions CAactions = new Actions();
 try {
    CActions.TryMe();
    //continue, all ok.
 }
 catch(Excepiton ex) {
      //hide a form, exception happens inside a method
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm wondering if is it a good practice to have a try-catch in the form class?

Comment: @PaulReed: sure, it's one of the ways to do that. Form class is your caller, so it knows what should happen if some call fails or succeed.

Comment: `throw exception;` will overwrite the original exception's call stack. Is it intended? Usually it is better to use just `throw;`

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid calling `MessageBox.Show()` anywhere, but on UI side of your application (e.g. your Form). It is considered a bad practice. So i would modify NDJ's answer:

```
public bool TryMe()
{
   try
   {
       SomeMethod();
       return true;
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
       //insert some logging here, if YOU need the callstack of your exception
       return false;
   }
}

if (CActions.TryMe())
{
    this.Hide();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(...); //insert some meaningful message, useful to END-USER here, not some "Null refrence exception!!11" message, which no one but you will understand
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as your code states, the `Exception` is being caught and it's `Message` property passed to a `MessageBox`. That means that, in no way, your code is being interrupted or the `Exception` given the opportunity to bubble up.

On a side note: it's considered somewhat bad practice to display a `MessageBox` in a class try/catch (or any other method for that matter). The reason for this is obvious: it makes your class dependent on being used in a graphical application environment and that goes against class reusability. It's better to propagate the `Exception` along a method return type that any type of application could handle, e.g. a string containing the `Message` and/or the `InnerException` text.

You could then do e.g.

```
string methodResult = myObject.MyMethod();
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(myMethodResult)) //... everything worked out ok
...
else //well then at least you have an error message to work with
```